# The argument type 'Future<Uint8List?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Uint8List>?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, pdf

I am trying to read the pdf from url using pdf, dio and printing packages but the weird thing is I am getting not one but three errors mentioned below. I have also attached the image for clear view where I am getting the errors.

```
The argument type 'Future<Uint8List?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Uint8List>?
The return type 'Uint8List?' isn't a 'FutureOr<Uint8List>', as required by the closure's context.
The argument type 'List<int>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'.
```

[image]

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _url =
      "https://www.au-sonpo.co.jp/corporate/upload/article/89/article_89_1.pdf";

  void _refresh() {
    setState(() {
      // other _url
      _url =
      "https://www.au-sonpo.co.jp/corporate/upload/article/90/article_90_1.pdf";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
        future:  _fetchPdfContent(_url),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return PdfPreview(
              allowPrinting: false,
              allowSharing: false,
              canChangePageFormat: false,
              initialPageFormat:
              PdfPageFormat(100 * PdfPageFormat.mm, 120 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
              build: (format)  =>  snapshot.data,
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _refresh,
        tooltip: 'Refesh',
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Uint8List?> _fetchPdfContent(final String url) async {
    try {
      final Response<List<int>> response = await Dio().get<List<int>>(
        url,
        options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes),
      );
      return Uint8List.fromList(response.data);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FutureBuilder expects a function that can be null, but the result of that function cannot be null, so what it expects is `Future<Uint8List>? _fetchPdfContent(final String url) async {...}`. For the null return one option would be to use an empty byte list and check the snapshots before displaying the widget.

Comment: Try understanding more about null safety, nullable operator, null-aware operator for better understanding of the specified error.https://dart.dev/null-safety#:~:text=Null%20safety%20prevents%20errors%20that,can%20be%20difficult%20to%20debug.

Answer (score 0):

In your `FutureBuilder`, you expect `Uint8List` but in your future you are return nullable type, Try this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _url =
      "https://www.au-sonpo.co.jp/corporate/upload/article/89/article_89_1.pdf";

  void _refresh() {
    setState(() {
      // other _url
      _url =
          "https://www.au-sonpo.co.jp/corporate/upload/article/90/article_90_1.pdf";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<Uint8List?>(
        future: _fetchPdfContent(_url),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return PdfPreview(
              allowPrinting: false,
              allowSharing: false,
              canChangePageFormat: false,
              initialPageFormat:
                  PdfPageFormat(100 * PdfPageFormat.mm, 120 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
              build: (format) => snapshot.data,
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _refresh,
        tooltip: 'Refesh',
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Uint8List?>? _fetchPdfContent(final String url) async {
    try {
      final Response<List<int>> response = await Dio().get<List<int>>(
        url,
        options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes),
      );
      if (response.data != null) {
        return Uint8List.fromList(response.data!);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: now i am receiving error for build: (format) => snapshot.data.                           The return type 'Uint8List?' isn't a 'FutureOr<Uint8List>', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: Are you copy exact code I wrote? It seems you are forgetting something

Comment: yes i copied paste the same

Comment: what package do you use for PdfPreview?

Comment: printing package

Comment: and what about for PdfPageFormat?

Comment: i do not have anything for formatting pdf

Comment: you are using it here : initialPageFormat:
                  PdfPageFormat(100 * PdfPageFormat.mm, 120 * PdfPageFormat.mm),

Answer (score 0):

**try this code**

```
 Future<Uint8List?> _fetchPdfContent(final String url) async {
   var Response<List<int>> response
   try {
    response  = await Dio().get<List<int>>(
       url,
       options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes),
     );
     
   } catch (e) {
     print(e);
     throw "put your error";
   }

  return Uint8List.fromList(response.data);
 }
```